# SAS proc sql do loop

Tags: sql, loops, sas

I am currently working on a credit card delinquency project. need help from expert to see if this can happen

so I have this code

```
data mcmc2;
set work.mcmc;
array delq(1:15) $2. delq_1-delq_15;

do i = 1 to 15;
delq(i) = substr(delq_36_rev, (i),2) ;
put @1 delq(i);
end;

run;
```

this code generate 15 variable from delq_36_rev

delq_36_rev looks like xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (where 0<=x<=7)
so delq_i looks like xx

**thing I want to do starts from here.**

from delq_1 ~ delq_15 I would give score based on numbers

(eg. 01 = 1 point, 12 = 2 points, 23= 3 points)

but I would also combine scores altogether

so I would like to write a do loop like

```
do i = 1 to 15
         when delq_i ="70" then score_i=-6 
         when delq_i in ("71","60") then score_i=-5 
         when delq_i in ("72","61","50") then score_i=-4
         when delq_i in ("73","62","51","40") then score_i=-3
         when delq_i in ("74","63","52","41","30") then score_i=-2
         when delq_i in ("76","65","65","64","54","53","43","42","32","31","20","21","10") then score_i=-1
         when delq_i ="00" then score_i=0
         when delq_i in ("01","11","22","33","44","55","66","77" then score_i=1      
         when delq_i ="12" then score_i=2 
         when delq_i ="23" then score_i=3
         when delq_i ="34" then score_i=4 
         when delq_i ="45" then score_i=5
         when delq_i ="56" then score_i=6 
         when delq_i ="67" then score_i=7

 sum(delq_1-delq_15) as delq_score
```

please help!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can do all of this easily in one data step, without resorting to macros:

```
data want;
  set set work.mcmc;
  array delq(15) $2. delq_1-delq_15;
  array score(15);
  do i = 1 to dim(delq);
    delq[i] = substr(delq_36_rev,i,2);
    select(delq[i]);
      when("70") score[i]=-6;
      when("71","60") score[i]=-5;
      /*etc*/
      otherwise call missing(score[i]);
    end;
  end;
  delq_score = sum(of score[*]);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an SQL update statement with `CASE` logic within a macro. But first add `score_1-score_15`columns along with your *delq* columns. Then in macro, update these *score* columns iteratively and in one last data step add them all up into `score`, finally dropping the 15 score items.

```
data mcm2;
    set work.mcmc;
    array delq(1:15) $2. delq_1-delq_15;
    array score(1:15) score_1-score_15;

    do i = 1 to 15;
        delq(i) = substr(delq_36_rev, (i),2) ;     * delq_1-delq_15;
        put @1 delq(i);
        score(i) = .;                              * score_1-score_15;
    end;
run;


%macro loopSQL;
    %do i = 1 %to 15;

        proc sql;
            UPDATE mcm2
            SET score_&i = 
             CASE 
                WHEN delq_&i ="70" THEN -6 
                WHEN delq_&i in ("71","60") THEN -5 
                WHEN delq_&i in ("72","61","50") THEN -4
                WHEN delq_&i in ("73","62","51","40") THEN -3
                WHEN delq_&i in ("74","63","52","41","30") THEN -2
                WHEN delq_&i in ("76","65","65","64","54","53","43","42","32","31","20","21","10") THEN -1
                WHEN delq_&i = "00" THEN 0
                WHEN delq_&i in ("01","11","22","33","44","55","66","77") THEN 1      
                WHEN delq_&i ="12" THEN 2 
                WHEN delq_&i ="23" THEN 3
                WHEN delq_&i ="34" THEN 4 
                WHEN delq_&i ="45" THEN 5
                WHEN delq_&i ="56" THEN 6 
                WHEN delq_&i ="67" THEN 7 
                ELSE .
            END;
        quit;

    %end;
%mend loopSQL;

%loopSQL;                                          * run macro;


data work.mcm2;
    set work.mcm2;

    score = sum(of score_1-score_15);   
    drop score_1-score_15;
run;
```